# If block not executing properly

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have a java web project, where I have a method to validate a user when he is logged in. I have made a password encryption service, to verify, rather his password is legit or not.

```
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");


    try {
        byte[] salt = LogicFacade.getSalt(email);

        byte[] attemptedPassword = LogicFacade.getEncryptedPassword(email);

        if (LogicFacade.authenticate(password, attempted password, salt))
//Here salt is null, whenever I try to log in, with a wrong username or password
 {
            User user = null;
            user = LogicFacade.login(email, password);
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            session.setAttribute("role", user.getRole());
            return user.getRole() + "page";
        } else {
            String errorMessage = "the username or password you have selected does not exist";
            throw new LoginSampleException(errorMessage);
        }

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | LoginSampleException ex ) {
        String errorMessage = "We have an internal problem, but we are working as hard as possible, to solve it.";
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new LoginSampleException(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

}

Whenever I type in a wrong username or password it says Salt-parameter must be non-null.

This is because I have a method to retrieve the salt from the user, from a SQL-database, which then returns null.

Here is my authenticate method:

```
  public boolean authenticate(String attemptedPassword, byte[] encryptedPassword, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, LoginSampleException {
        // Encrypt the clear-text password using the same salt that was used to
        // encrypt the original password
        byte[] encryptedAttemptedPassword = getEncryptedPassword(attemptedPassword, salt);

        // Authentication succeeds if encrypted password that the user entered
        // is equal to the stored hash
        return Arrays.equals(encryptedPassword, encryptedAttemptedPassword);
    }
```

My question is why it does not execute the else block after the if-condition is not met. Whenever I debug the project, it goes straight to the thread-class after I try to dig into the method?

Is it possible that it can enter the else block and not immediately throw a NullPointerException?

Comment: You need to thoroughly debug your code. We can't do this for you. The only reason I can imagine is that `LogicFacade.authenticate(...)` throws an exception. But it can be something else as well.

Comment: The above does not even compile - your if statement is missing the second ). Please be much more carefully when posting code!

Comment: that was a typo i apologize. Yes the authenticate methods throws an nullPointerException, however i'm not aware of why, because one value is null, should it not return false instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if condition to,

```
if (salt!=null && LogicFacade.authenticate(password, attempted password, salt)){
...if-block
} else {
...else-block
}
```

As salt null means provided email doesn't exists in your database.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your if block is inside the try block, when an exception is thrown, the control shifts to catch block and then the program exits

To correct this mistake, you can just check

```
if(salt==null)
```

Hope it helps!